# Alter client.dns.lookup in MSK connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I have an AWS MSK managed connector which seems to use this default configuration - `client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips`

I'd like to change this value but when I try set `client.dns.lookup` in connector configurations it appears that it makes no difference.  Could it be that it's not supported or am i specifying it incorrectly?

`client.dns.lookup=resolve_canonical_bootstrap_servers_only`

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since understood this is not possible.  Custom worker configuration does not support this value, nor does it support `producer.override`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-workers.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to duplicate the value with a prefix of `producer.override.` and/or `consumer.override.` respectively for source/sink to alter client behavior within a connector.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running

Otherwise, you need access to modify the worker properties with that config.